# Explicit maps behind the isomorphism $k \otimes V \cong V$

Tags: abstract-algebra

This question is undoubtably extremely trivial, especially since every text I read gives only the forward direction map behind the isomorphism $k\otimes V \cong V$, i.e. $\lambda \otimes v \mapsto \lambda v$.

Please can someone state what exactly the inverse to this map is?

many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that a property of tensor products is that $s(u\otimes v) = (su) \otimes v = u\otimes (sv)$ for any scalar $s\in k$ and elements $u\in U$ and $v\in V$.

Using this for the special case of $k\otimes V$, you can see that $v \mapsto 1\otimes v$ is an inverse to the map $k \otimes v \mapsto kv$.

Comment: that's great, thanks!